# Disable automount of removable media in GNOME/Nautilus

Tags: linux, mount, gnome3, nautilus, automount

Using GNOME 3, how can I disable automounting removable media and if possible, do so using the drive ID?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work, but haven't tested it:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open false
```